# Убрать watermark с сайта. Нет возможности редактирования HTML, есть возможность редактирования CSS

Tags: html, css

Всем привет!
Нужно убрать эту water-марку:

```
<div class="d-flex" style="display: flex !important; opacity: 1 !important; transform: none !important; position: inherit !important; visibility: visible !important;">
                        <a class="footer-brand mr-3 my-auto" href="https://shop.ikdan.ru" style="display: block !important; opacity: 1 !important; transform: none !important; position: inherit !important; visibility: visible !important;">
                            <img src="//cp.easydonate.ru/storage/app/media/defaults/easydonate.svg" style="border-radius: 8px; display: block !important; opacity: 1 !important; transform: none !important; position: inherit !important; visibility: visible !important;">
                        </a>
                        <p class="small mb-0" style="display: inline !important; opacity: 1 !important; transform: none !important; position: inherit !important; visibility: visible !important; font-size: 80% !important">
                            © 2022 - 2023 NeonLand.<br>
                                                            Создано с помощью <a href="//easydonate.ru" target="_blank" class="text-warning text-shadow-warning" style="display: inline !important; opacity: 1 !important; transform: none !important; position: inherit !important; visibility: visible !important;">EasyDonate</a>.
                                                    </p>
                    </div>
```

> https://shop.ikdan.ru/

В самом низу страницы

Comment: inline important нельзя перебить. Только убрать из разметки

Comment: Если вы используете бесплатный конструктор сайтов, то, скорее всего, скрытие ватермарка приведёт к блокировке сайта :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.footer .d-flex {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
}
```

Comment: Помог, от души!

Answer (score 0):

Полностью убрать, скорее всего, не получится.

Можно добавить к ненужным классам:

```
."класс"{
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Не работает, я добавил, никаких изменений нет(

Comment: В самом html стоит запрет с помощью "!important".

Возможно, поможет способ удаления полного узла с помощью js.

Comment: Ещё можно попытаться так:

."класс"{
  position: absolute !important;
  display: none !important;
  visibility: hidden !important;
}

Comment: Не работает( Попробовал ласт  position: absolute !important; display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important;

Comment: тогда только js

Answer (score 0):

Но это уберёт лишь визуально её.

```css
.d-flex {
  margin-left: -10000px;
}
```

Comment: Помогло, но многие части страницы улетели тоже(

Answer (score 0):

Легко

```
#footer .d-flex {
  all: unset;
  position: absolute;
  left: -100vw;
  top: -100vh;
}
```

#### Объяснение

Сначала, убираем все стили у элемента с помощью `all: unset;`, а далее уже применяем те стили, которые мы хотим. Но важно чтобы они были **после** `all: unset;`, чтобы сам он не аннулировал пропорции которые мы применим.

Comment: Нет(
Осталась марка

Answer (score 0):

```
footer.footer,footer.footer *{
  height:0!important;
  width:0!important;
  font-size:0!important;
  padding:0!important}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]